# Subtract an array object

Tags: modifiers

I am working on micro patterns. I want to subtract an array object from a cylinder using Boolean modifier. It is simply subtracting squares from a cylinder. Can someone please simply guide me through with steps such as;

1- Create the array

2- Select array object you want to subtract 
etc.

-If there is anyone who could do it since there are around 625000 squares you will probably need a computer with at least 32 GB ram capacity (I can't). However it is a simple 5 minute work and I would appreciate help a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: If it's really THIS many objects, I'd rather recommend building the microstructure itself as an array directly, rather than boolean it out of somewhere. This will process a lot faster, display faster, and give a WAY cleaner mesh output. You'll need to add a precise screenshot / description so we understand what you try to achieve exactly. Like how many divisions, what size, which spacing, etc etc.

Comment: @alias hope this helps 
http://imgur.com/gallery/FFOfn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a bit with this task, creating the basic setup. The screenshots are kinda helpful, but don't tell the full story yet. So in essence, I've created a flat plane with the microstructure on it, and a cylinder wall with the structure on it. Both use the same mesh, all you need to model is this here:

[image: base mesh]

It's a cube with the top face deleted, and then three faces extruded out of that. The cube has the desired 100 um size. Using arrays with the merge option turned on, and the merge tolerance set to something really low like 10 um, you'll get the flat plane with the structure. If you need that with a circular cut around it, you can use one boolean. I didn't do that so far, as I'm not sure where this is going yet.

The sidewall is the same mesh, just one additional modifier added after the arrays: The Bend modifier. I used an Empty to control the direction. And this is what it looks like on the cylinder:

[image: on cylinder]

The Blend file is here: [image]

## Based on your own model

**Edit** Updated Blend file is here: [image]

As stated in the comment section, I cannot upload the file with modifiers applied, as there is a limit of 30 MB at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, and the resulting file is 32MB. By the way, how does blender crash on your end? Because if what you see is Blender freezing for a while, that's just because the modifier calculation takes a long time. On my machine 30 seconds, and this is a real beast. So if that's the case for you, just be patient  :)

Comment: First of all thank you for these. But as  I also mentioned I can't reach to a high end computer right now. Which in this case causes Blender to crash after I open the file.  Considering you made this file I think you could be able to work on mine. [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1740" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1740/)

Comment: And if you don't mind could you share your setup with with. I would appreciate it.

Comment: @KeithN do you just want to cut these objects out of the base? Or also on the sidewalls?

Comment: Just the base, sidewalls may be needed later but not now.

Comment: Try this: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1742" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1742/)

Comment: I'd like to upload the file with applied modifiers too, but it is more than 30MB, which is not allowed on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @KeithN I've added more info to my answer